# Can't update data variables using functions inside functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Good morning everyone. Here's the problem:

My goal is to update playerAttackDamage, playerSpeed and playerAccuracy. I created the statChange method mainly for the DRY principle, since there will be many more variables to update, but it doesn't work as intended. The stat gets updated inside the statChange method, but then returns to its original value. If I log the value, I see it updated inside the statChange method, but back to its previous value inside the attackUp function. My guess is the statChange method copies the variable and updates it, instead of updating the original one. Either way, what can I do to update permanently the value? If I do that without using the statChange method, it works perfectly, but as I said, the code would become much longer and repetitive. Any help is deeply appreciated. Here's the code:

Have a good day, y'all!

````
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        playerAccuracy: 50,
        playerAttackDamage: 0,
        playerSpeed: 0,
        monsterSpeed: 2
        turns: []
    },
    methods: {

        checkTurnOrder: function(action) {
            if (this.playerSpeed > this.monsterSpeed) {
                action();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.monsterTurn();
                }, 1000);
                
            } else {
                this.monsterTurn();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    action();
                }, 1000);
            }
        },

        statChange: function(stat, change, statName) {
            stat += change;
            this.turns.unshift({
                isPlayer: true,
                text: this.capitalize(statName) + ' stat raised by ' + change + '. Current ' + statName + ': ' + stat
            })
        },

        attackUp: function() {
            var yourTurn = () => {
                this.statChange(this.playerAttackDamage, 2, 'attack')
            }
            this.checkTurnOrder(yourTurn);

        },

        speedUp: function() {
            var yourTurn = () => {
                this.statChange(this.playerSpeed, 2, 'speed')
            }
            this.checkTurnOrder(yourTurn);
        },

        accUp: function() {
            var yourTurn = () => {
                this.statChange(this.playerAccuracy, 10, 'accuracy')
        }
        this.checkTurnOrder(yourTurn);
        },
    },
});```
````

Comment: at first view it seems that `var yourTurn` has no value. I would write a `return` before each this.stateChange... or make a one liner out of it (without return) - like: `var yourTurn = () => this.statChange(this.playerAccuracy, 10, 'accuracy')` what happens then?

Comment: I tried both ways. Apparently it doesn't change anything

Comment: where do you plan to assign the new values? in you code example is no assignemt for like `this.playerAttackDamage = NewValue`. You just pass the player stats as arguments, which of course are static at the moment....

Comment: Well, when in the statChange method you see stat+= change, it should get translated into this.playerAttackDamage += 2, so there is the assignment

Comment: this is only a scoped assignment in your function block. to change the reactive data in vue, you have to write something like `this.playerAttackDamage = change`.

Comment: this.player[statName] += change works, until the code stays inside the statChange method. Once the method is over, this.player[statName] gets reverted back to its previous value

Comment: I tried assigning as you suggested, but it still doesn't work. I used stat = change inside the statChange method, and this.player[statName], this.player[statName]+x as params

Answer (score 0):

here is a example of the workflow.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   playerAttackDamage: 0
  },
  methods: {
    statChange(stat, change, statName) {
      this[statName] = stat += change // the line to change the state
      return 'value to turn order'
   },
   attackUp() {
     const yourTurn = this.statChange(this.playerAttackDamage, 2, 'playerAttackDamage')
     this.checkTurnOrder(yourTurn);
    },
   checkTurnOrder(yourTurn) {
     console.log(yourTurn);
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <p>player attack: {{ playerAttackDamage }}</p>
  <button @click="attackUp">attackUp</button>
</div>
```

It is not clean, I know, but you can get an idea how to change the state

Comment: I can't use it like this. I need yourTurn to be a function, otherwise the checkTurnOrder function you can see in the main post stops working

Comment: keep in mind it's all about `this[statName] = stat += change`

Comment: that's good to hear. sorry if it took longer.